# Accessibility label wih iOS ViewController presented as a form sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing, accessibility, kif

I am making use of a Presentation: Form Sheet in my app. So my ViewController gets displayed as a form with the black semi-transparent overlay around it.

I have implemented the logic to dismiss everything should the user tap anywhere outside my form sheet ViewController.

I would like to test this behavior but I'm not sure how to simulate the tap. How can I set an accessibility label to simulate this tap with a UI test?

Or any other suggestions how I can test this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to click anywhere on the screen to dismiss everything?

```
    [tester tapScreenAtPoint:CGPoint];
```

does that for you.

Most stuff about KIF is explained here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/61419/ios-ui-testing-with-kif

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use **UITapGestureRecognizer** like this :

First create an instance of UITapGestureRecognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:)];
```

Then attach this gesture recognizer to your view (i.e, black overlay you're talking about )

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Then implement **someMethod:** which is the method (action) that gets called when your formsheet is tapped

```
-(void)someMethod
{
 //Logic to dismiss your formsheet 
}
```

HTH :D

Comment: If I was writing unit tests, that could indeed help but my scenario is more suited to a UI test isn't it? I am using KIF and all the steps are triggered by a tap on an element based on an accessibility label and/or identifier.